# AtributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'plt' - Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm very new with these libraries and i'm having troubles while plotting this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

df5 = pd.read_csv('../../../../datos/tiempos-exacto-variando-n-m0.csv', sep=', ', engine='python')
print(df5)
df5['n'] = df5['n'].apply(lambda x: x**2)
sns.jointplot(df5['n'], df5['tiempoTotal'], kind="reg")
sns.plt.show()
```

And i'm getting this output:

```
 n  m  tiempoTotal
0      1  0         2274
1      2  0         3370
2      3  0         5709
3      4  0         8959
4      5  0        13354
5      6  0        18503
6      7  0        26329
7      8  0        33859
8      9  0        41110
9     10  0        52710
10    11  0        64364
11    12  0        74142
12    13  0        81072
13    14  0        69332
14    15  0        71027
15    16  0        89721
16    17  0        85459
17    18  0        95217
18    19  0       119210
19    20  0       136888
20    21  0       131903
21    22  0       138395
22    23  0       151222
23    24  0       163542
24    25  0       177236
25    26  0       192475
26    27  0       240162
27    28  0       260701
28    29  0       235752
29    30  0       250835
..   ... ..          ...
580  581  0     88306854
581  582  0     89276420
582  583  0     87457875
583  584  0     90807004
584  585  0     87790003
585  586  0     89821530
586  587  0     89486585
587  588  0     88496901
588  589  0     89090661
589  590  0     89110803
590  591  0     90397942
591  592  0     94029839
592  593  0     92749859
593  594  0    105991135
594  595  0     95383921
595  596  0    105155207
596  597  0    114193414
597  598  0     98108892
598  599  0     97888966
599  600  0    103802453
600  601  0     97249346
601  602  0    101917488
602  603  0    104943847
603  604  0     98966140
604  605  0     97924262
605  606  0     97379587
606  607  0     97518808
607  608  0     99839892
608  609  0    100046492
609  610  0    103857464

[610 rows x 3 columns]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-63146953b89d> in <module>()
      9 df5['n'] = df5['n'].apply(lambda x: x**2)
     10 sns.jointplot(df5['n'], df5['tiempoTotal'], kind="reg")
---> 11 sns.plt.show()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'plt'
```

I'm running this in my `Jupyter Notebook` with `Python 2.7.12`. Any ideas?

Comment: Should be just `plt.show()` without `sns`.

Comment: I would not close this question, because `sns.plt.show()` is supposed to work and leaving it open might give someone the option to provide an answer on which versions of seaborn are supporting it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Why do you say it's "supposed to work?" That doesn't appear anywhere in the documentation and anywhere `matplotlib.pyplot` is used it's imported directly.

Comment: @mwaskom I was assuming that because it is working. And only because something is not documented, we cannot assume that it is not supposed to work. But in any case, you are probably the one to give a definitive answer here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest relevant PR is [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/912).

Comment: What is the conclusion to draw from this? Would it be best not to rely on seaborn making pyplot available?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest there was never a "wrapper" for `pyplot` in seaborn, you just can access objects that are in the top-level namespace unless you take effort not to. e.g. you can import matplotlib and then do `matplotlib.numpy` to get numpy. But it doesn't mean you ever should.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`sns.plt.show()` works fine for me using seaborn 0.7.1. Could be that this is different in other versions. However, if you anyways `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` you may as well simply use `plt.show()`, as `sns.plt.show()` is only working because `pyplot` is available inside the seaborn namespace.

Answer (score 16):

Well, I ran into this issue as well with Seaborn 0.8.1. Turns out being able to call `sns.plt.show()` is bad practice and the fact that it worked [was a bug](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1239) which the developer fixed. Unfortunately, there are many tutorials [out there](https://www.google.com/search?q=sns.plt.show()) that still advise one to use `sns.plt.show()`. This is how I solved it:

1. Import plt directly: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
2. Before you plot anything, set the default aesthetic parameters: `sns.set()` - important, because otherwise you won't get the Seaborn palettes.
3. Replace all calls to `sns.plt` with `plt`

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks. I feel this should be accepted as the answer instead.

Answer (score 6):

As of Seaborn 0.8.1, `sns.plt.plot()` raises the error `module 'seaborn' has no attribute 'plt'`.

`sns.plot()` also raises an error; these methods are not in ***[Seaborn's API](https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html)***.

Dropping the “sns.” to leave “plt.plot()” (as other answers suggest) does work, but only because we've called the **sns.set()** method in place earlier in the script... i.e. *Seaborn is making an aesthetic change: **Matplotlib is still the object**, which does the plotting, via its **plt.plot()** method*.

***[This script](https://git.generalassemb.ly/oisteadman/python-unit-5-exercises/blob/master/demo_sns.set)*** shows **sns.set()** in action... if you follow the comments and swap *sns.set()* between different locations in the script, it changes the appearance of the subplots. They look like Seaborn plots, but Matplotlib is doing the plotting.

Seaborn does of course have a load of its own plot methods (like sns.boxplot(), sns.violinplot() etc) but there is no longer a method **sns.plt.plot()**.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to confirm that I got the same error using Jupyter inside Anaconda (Feb 2018). Got the code from [here](https://python-graph-gallery.com/74-density-plot-of-several-variables/) but the error occured. It turns out that I need to simply add

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

on top of

```
import seaborn as sns
```

and it work just fine using `plt.show()` instead of `sns.plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have updated your python shell as well IDE's like Anaconda. 
Like I had a constant error in Spyder (Hosted under Anaconda) with relplot and catplot until I updated Anaconda as well as seaborn (0.90).
Updating via the Anaconda commandline should be pretty straightforward like in my case.